# VS 2010: Why the "Autos" window items appear\disappear in their visibility area?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Windows 7 x64; MS Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I press the F10 key step by step into DEBUG mode, and look the "Autos" window items. I see some variables (in the "Autos" window) sometime appears/disappears in their visibility area (and they are already initialized). Why it happen? Look the screens below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autos window shows things the debugger thinks you may be interested in relation to where you are in the code. It's automagic, so it's impossible to explain exactly what the logic is. Use `locals` or `watch` windows if you need to have a more constant view.

Comment: I seem to remember it shows things related to the current line, the previous line and the next line.

Comment: @xen-0: Yes, something along those lines. But it is still some sort of "magic" involved in figuring it out, because sometimes it shows things you don't expect, and sometimes it doesn't show something you DO expect.